# How can I look up all CloudTrail events from all regions using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a quick question about **how to get all CloudTrail events from all regions with boto3**.

When I run the following script, it only lists up the instances from the CloudTrail home region (which means the region that CloudTrail was created).

```
response = trail.lookup_events(
    LookupAttributes = [
        {
            'AttributeKey': 'EventName',
            'AttributeValue': 'RunInstances'
        }
    ],
    StartTime = datetime(2021,8,21),
    EndTime = datetime(2021,8,24),
)
```

**Is there any way that I can get all the CloudTrail events from all regions?**

Thanks for your help in advance!

*FYI, the MultiRegion option is on for my CloudTrail.*

Answer (score 1):

Changing region with boto3 config will work.

I use the `regions_work_with_service` function below as a snippet for getting all regions. And then loop with regions to do something.

Below, `client = boto3.client("cloudtrail", config=my_config)` set one region, and the client run `lookup_events` and events are printed (if any).

```py
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config


def regions_work_with_service(service):
    regions = []
    client = boto3.client(service)
    response = client.describe_regions()

    for item in response["Regions"]:
        regions.append(item["RegionName"])

    return regions


regions = regions_work_with_service("ec2")

for region in regions:

    print(f"region: {region}")

    my_config = Config(region_name=region)
    client = boto3.client("cloudtrail", config=my_config)

    response = client.lookup_events(
        LookupAttributes=[
            {"AttributeKey": "EventName", "AttributeValue": "RunInstances"}
        ]
    )

    if response["Events"]:
        for i in range(len(response["Events"])):
            event = json.loads(response["Events"][i]["CloudTrailEvent"])
            print(event)
```